# how to visit page using requests with cookie?

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, python-requests

I want to visit zoomeye.org using requests module, the cookie from firebug is as follows:

__jsluid=470133a1338c0be13b6fdccf396772c3; csrftoken=WG6eSMS9XaLZfLjICiin8esg1qO3UOFl; Hm_lvt_e58da53564b1ec3fb2539178e6db042e=1448411456; Hm_lpvt_e58da53564b1ec3fb2539178e6db042e=1448505898; __jsl_clearance=1448505830.313|0|EwXSRp%2BrIEF5DR0E5WALlzLMV2Q%3D

The scripts to read web page content:

```
import requests
headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Host": "www.zoomeye.org",
    "Referer": "https://www.zoomeye.org/",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"
}
data = open("cookie.txt", "r").read()
cookieDict = {}
for item in data.split(";"):
    keyValue = item.split("=")
    cookieDict[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1]    
url = "https://www.zoomeye.org/search?q=apache"
r = requests.get(url,cookies=cookieDict, headers=headers)
print r.content
```

But i fail to read web page content,  output as follows:

```
<script>var dc="";var t_d={hello:"world",t_c:function(x){if(x==="")return;if(x.s
lice(-1)===";"){x=x+" ";};if(x.slice(-2)!=="; "){x=x+"; ";};dc=dc+x;}};(function
(a){eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?"":e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c
=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){
while(c--)d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\
w+'};c=1;};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);
return p;}('b d=[5,4,0,1,2,3];b o=[];b p=0;g(b i=d.c;i--;){o[d[i]]=a[i]}o=o.m(\'
\');g(b i=0;i<o.c;i++){l(o.q(i)===\';\'){s(o,p,i);p=i+1}}s(o,p,o.c);j s(t,r,n){k
.h(t.y(r,n))};w("f.e=f.e.v(/[\\?|&]u-x/, \'\')",z);',36,36,'|||||||||||var|lengt
h||href|location|for|t_c||function|t_d|if|join||||charAt||||captcha|replace|setT
imeout|challenge|substring|1500'.split('|'),0,{}));})(['45 GMT;Path=/;', ' 26-No
v-15 03:52:', '__jsl_clearance=1448506365.', '687|0|rtcCTV', 'xuWxRiE8%2BC0', 'W
WncvYkCpQ%3D;Expires=Thu,']);document.cookie=dc;</script>
```

where the problem is?if you know a better solution for this question, please tell me. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do? Make a POST request?

Comment: Hmm...looks like your cookies split by `; `(there's a space after that `;`). But you're using `for item in data.split(";")`, try `for item in data.split("; ")`.

Comment: Also, if the website use javascript, maybe you should take a look at [**selenium**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Comment: @Kevin Guan:  When using firefox visits the page such as "https://www.zoomeye.org/search?q=apache", The website  first send a piece of javascript code above back to firefox, and then firefox generates cookie and then makes GET request for target url("https://www.zoomeye.org/search?q=apache"). In my code i copy the cookie from firebug plugin of firefox and save into cookie.txt, and then make request for the target url, because i don’t know how to execute js in python.

Comment: It's not the User-Agent, it's a **`p,a,c,k,e,d`** JavaScript security measure. Once you understand how it works you will be able to solve the challenge (yes, you can do it with Python), get a good cookie and navigate without any problem.

Comment: @ Andrés Pérez-Albela H.: I just failed using pyv8 to execute the javascript code above in my python code, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the website does not like your user agent. Remove the user agent header and it will work.